# How to use String array in another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have 2 activities. Each extends Activity. I tried all ways I found here, but none of them was working.
I need to send String array from one to other activity, but stay in first activity.
I try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityFrom.this, ActivityTo.class);
                                                intent.putExtra("string-array", ARRAY);
                                                ActivityFrom.this.startActivity(intent);
```

And to recive:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
        String[] array = intent.getExtras().getStringArray("string-array");
```

Any idea?

Comment: did U tried with intent.putStringArrayListExtra(name, value);?

Comment: You could used SharedPreferences.

Comment: When I start activity like: startActivity(intent);

Comment: When activity stars by this:    startActivity(intent);    it covers whole screen and to continue i have to end it.  Any idea here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray("key", strarray);
Intent intent=new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: When activity stars by this:    startActivity(intent);    it covers whole screen and to continue i have to end it.  Any idea here?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a Singleton class, this will also make your String array available throughout your application, if you so desire to use it later on. Something like this should get you started:

```
public class StringArrayHolder {
    private static StringArrayHolder instance;
    private String[] mArray;

    public static StringArrayHolder getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new StringArrayHolder();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private StringArrayHolder() {

    }

    public void setStringArray(String[] value) {
        mArray = value;
    }

    public String[] getStringArray() {
        return mArray;
    }

}
```

You could also use the [putStringArrayListExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putStringArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a anti-pattern on Android. You should use the provided methods (bundles and extras) for passing objects to and from Activities.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `public Intent putExtra (String name, Bundle value)` where your `Bundle` object contains the `String[]` array using `putStringArray(String key, String[] value)`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you

```
ActivityFrom.java:
...
    // Start ActivityTo
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTo.class);
    intent.getExtras().putStringArray("string-array", ARRAY);
    startActivity(intent); 
...

ActivityTo.java:
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] strings = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("string-array");
    ...
}
```

Comment: When activity stars by this:    startActivity(intent);    it covers whole screen and to continue i have to end it.  Any idea here?

Comment: What do you mean by "continue"?
The application activities are usually fullscreen on Android. If you have a question regarding creating an application that only covers parts of the screen, I suggest you create a separate question for this.